# Getting EOF error that I don't know how to fix, so I can submit zyBook assignment

Tags: python

The question i'm being asked to complete is:

Many documents use a specific format for a person's name. Write a program that reads a person's name in the following format:

```
firstName middleName lastName (in one line)
```

and outputs the person's name in the following format:

```
lastName, firstInitial.middleInitial.
```

My code:
# Promt user for first, middle, and last name

```
first_name = input()
middle_name = input()
last_name = input()

# Print the user's input as such: lastName, fistInitial.middleInitial

print(last_name + ',', first_name[0] + '.', middle_name[0] + '.')
```

I am getting the correct output in developer mode, but when I submit it I'm receiving error.

[image]

Comment: The directions state the user input is coming in as a single line.  That means you can only use one `input()`, and then have to split the input into pieces.

Comment: The zyBook environment only provides one line of input.  So when you call `input()` the second time, there is nothing left to read, and you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
full_name = input("Enter full name (firstName middleName lastName): ")

name_parts = full_name.split()

first_name = name_parts[0]
middle_name = name_parts[1]
last_name = name_parts[2]

print(last_name + ',', first_name[0] + '.', middle_name[0] + '.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any validation it's just:

```
first, middle, last = input().split()

print(f'{last}, {first[0]}.{middle[0]}.')
```

This is only guaranteed to work if the input is exactly as stated - i.e., 3 whitespace delimited strings (tokens)